# Travis-CI Gem Deploy Not Working

Tags: ruby, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

EDIT: **At this point I am able to compile my gem on travis-ci but it is NOT deploying to rubygem.org and there is no error.  Below is all my configuration.  I need help figuring out what needs to exist in order to deploy a gem to rubygem from travis-ci?**

I'm attempting to follow the [instructions](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/rubygems/) for adding rubygem deployment to my build.

My project is the [azure-documentdb-sdk](https://github.com/adammartin/azure-documentdb-rubysdk).  I have configured my yml fire using the command `travis setup rubygems`

Here is the actual [.travis.yml](https://github.com/adammartin/azure-documentdb-rubysdk/blob/master/.travis.yml) file on github.

The travis build is [here](https://travis-ci.org/adammartin/azure-documentdb-rubysdk/builds/75730473) for tag [v0.0.4](https://github.com/adammartin/azure-documentdb-rubysdk/releases/tag/v0.0.4).

Because this is my first attempt to use travis-ci I'm at a complete loss on what to do.  I believe I've followed all the proper steps but clearly I have a user error buried in here somewhere.

I really want to automate deployment.

EDIT: After some great comments let me clarify:

Per the [log file](https://travis-ci.org/adammartin/azure-documentdb-rubysdk/jobs/75735201) we have a deployment occurring

```
Deploying application
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: azure-documentdb-sdk
  Version: 0.0.6
  File: azure-documentdb-sdk-0.0.6.gem
```

If I look though the gem is [NOT deploying](https://rubygems.org/gems/azure-documentdb-sdk).  There is no version 0.0.6 deployed.

How do I get travis-ci to deploy my compiled artifact.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? What exactly not working? Could you please localize the problem?

Comment: Fundamentally why is the deployment not working?  It does not autodeploy the gem.  I have to manually install the gem still yet I am following all the instructions ... or at least I think I am.

Comment: it's **too broad** - _why is the deployment not working_?.

Comment: That's just it ... I don't know ...

Comment: Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: OH wait ... I have while copying the log files found out that not all the information is necessarily printed lol ... that's not awesome ... here is what the log file has hidden:  ERROR:  Gemspec file not found: azure-documentdb-rubysdk.gemspec

Comment: Here is the gemspec though https://github.com/adammartin/azure-documentdb-rubysdk/blob/master/azure-documentdb-sdk.gemspec

Comment: Ahh I think it's a name mismatch

Comment: Ok still not it here is the output of the latest changes (and thanks for the good questions):   Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: azure-documentdb-sdk
  Version: 0.0.6
  File: azure-documentdb-sdk-0.0.6.gem  .... so why is it not deploying?

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.  Could you please use the edit link to add the information to the question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.  The problem came down to the gemspec name did not match the name of the gem we were going to deploy to.  So the the gemspec was `azure-documentdb-rubysdk.gemspec` and the gem was `azure-documentdb-sdk`

By changing the name of the gemspec and correcting the `.travis.yml` to reference the new name under the `gem:` setting the build now deploys.